# Jquery not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a toggle panel to show and hide the additional div.Please find my code snippet of the function below. It is working fine in Chrome,Safari&Firefox . It is not working on IE 9 alone. Please help.

```
 handleExpandClick : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.currentTarget).hide("slow");
        var nextElem = e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
        $(nextElem).slideDown("slow");


    }
```

Comment: Explain the term 'not working'. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In IE9 the click happens and the expandable div which is supposed to expand never happens.

Comment: Next element in the code which is supposed to be a div is now shown in IE 9.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
handleExpandClick : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide("slow"); // you may use e.target instead of this
        var nextElem = $(this).parent().next();
        nextElem.slideDown("slow");
    }
```

Comment: I am getting the following error on trying @The System Restart Code on Chrome

'Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'next''

Comment: @Ravi you can use `e.target` instead of `this`. It'll be better if you make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Guys Thanks for all the response.Sorry.When I closed my Developer tools and cleared the cache.My Old code is working now suddenly in IE 9:)

Comment: @Ravi Glad to hear that ur code works, but you accept this as answer for this because this code is more well that your

Comment: @TheSystemRestart I accepted it and +1 all your comments. Thanks for your sincere time and efforts